# How would I go about accessing multiple files as an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, file, require

I have a batch of json files that I am requiring and assigning independent variables. How would I got about importing every file in a folder as a separate variable stored in an array? I've looked everywhere and cannot find a straight answer. Thanks!

Comment: The trouble is that you need a server side script to do this, which JavaScript is not.

Comment: javascript is a client-side language but, frameworks such as nodejs,angular js etc would allow you to do so.

Comment: @coletrain I'm using node.

Comment: @durbnpoisn I'm using node

Comment: That STILL involves having something on the server side.  And since you need the server, you are WAY better off using ASP or PHP (whichever is available).